# How to retrieve images from a url in a pandas dataframe and store them as PIL object in a new column

Tags: python, pandas, image-preprocessing

I'm trying to store as a PIL object in a new column of a dataframe pictures that are located in a column of the same dataframe in the form of URL's.

I've tried the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image
import requests
from io import BytesIO

pictures = [None] * 2

df = pd.DataFrame({'project_id':["1", "2"], 
                    'image_url':['http://www.personal.psu.edu/dqc5255/gl-29.jpg',
                                'https://www.iprotego.com/wp-content/uploads/google.jpg']})

df.insert(2, "pictures", pictures, True)

for i in range(2):
    r = requests.get(df.iloc[i,1]) 
    df.iloc[i,2] = Image.open(BytesIO(r.content))

df
```

I expected to get a dataframe with this structure but including both training examples:

```
    project_id                  image_url                                  pictures
0       1    http://www.personal.psu.edu/dqc5255/gl-29.jpg <PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=400x300 at 0x116EF9AC8>
```

But instead got the following error:

````
OSError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x116ec2f10>
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just changed the `User-agent` in the for loop so that now the request line in the loop is: `r = requests.get(df.iloc[i,1], headers=headers)` with `headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/XXX.XX (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/XX.X.XXXX.XXX Safari/XXX.XX'}` and this solved the error. I also added a `r.raise_for_status()` to check the status before using the `r.content`

Final code:

`````
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image
import requests
from io import BytesIO

df = pd.DataFrame({'project_id':["1", "2"], 
                    'image_url':['http://www.personal.psu.edu/dqc5255/gl-29.jpg',
                                'https://www.iprotego.com/wp-content/uploads/google.jpg']})

pictures = [None] * 2

df.insert(2, "pictures", pictures, True)

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/xxx.xx (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/xx.x.xxxx.xxx Safari/xxx.xx'}

for i in range(2):
    r = requests.get(df.iloc[i,1], headers=headers)
    r.raise_for_status()
    df.iloc[i,2] = Image.open(BytesIO(r.content))

df
````
`````